# 2000 Hyndai Elantra

Tags: radiator, thermostat

My car keep over heating. The fans are operational, thermostat has been replaced, new water pump has been put in, hoses and clamps have been replaced and radiator cap is new also the radiator has been checked for leaks but its still overheats while stopped or idle... any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Several things need to be done here:

1) Was the factory procedure for removing air from the cooling system followed (called burping the system by many techs)

2) was the system back flushed maybe there is sediment in it?

3) Was the new thermostat tested in a pan of boiling water to see if it opens

4) Was the cooling water checked for the presence of exhaust compounds indicating a head gasket leak?

5) Were the radiator fins cleaned?

6) Is oil level low?

7) Is the lower radiator hose collapsing in because the spring in it is broken or weak?